# Connecting nodejs to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I am using [this package](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) with express-js and I have this connection settings but it returns an error:

> TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string.

Configuration:

```
const config = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    user: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'PASSWORD',
    database: 'My_DATABASE_NAME',
    server: '120.000000.000,3306/SQLSERVER2014',
});
```

and then this code to execute procedure

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool =>{
        return pool.request()
        // .execute('procedure_name')
        .query('select * from AspNetUsers');
    }).then(result => {
        console.dir(result)
        pool.close();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        pool.close();
    });
});
```

Any idea what might be the issue with `server` value?

Comment: Try fill server IP address to `server` property.

Comment: @hoangdv you mean only ip address? if so i already tried it result was the same

Comment: I give you a answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The lib document does not said like your example code. You push a `ConnectionPool` instance (stores in `config` variable) to `connect` function of `sql`.

I think, you need choose one way to query data from mssql server:

1. `ConnectionPool`, reuse your code, create a connection pool, then use it.

```
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({ // `pool` - clear variable name
  user: 'USERNAME',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  database: 'My_DATABASE_NAME',
  server: 'localhost', // Example
});


//
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  pool.connect() // just call .connect
    .then(() => {
      return pool.request() // use `pool` const
        // .execute('procedure_name')
        .query('select * from AspNetUsers');
    }).then(result => {
      console.dir(result)
      pool.close();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      pool.close();
    });
});
```

2. Create new connection pool for each time when you want to query data.

```
const config = { // A "normal" json object
  user: 'USERNAME',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  database: 'My_DATABASE_NAME',
  server: 'localhost', // Example
};


//
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  const pool = null;
  sql.connect(config) // create new connection pool
    .then(newPool => {
      pool = newPool;
      return pool.request()
        // .execute('procedure_name')
        .query('select * from AspNetUsers');
    }).then(result => {
      console.dir(result)
      pool.close();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      pool && pool.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, with using your method `1` i get `ConnectionError: Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to different database.` and with your method `2` i get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: pool is not defined`

Comment: @mafortis Method 2,  Check again `sql.connect(config).then(pool => {...` line.

Comment: still sayas `ReferenceError: pool is not defined` should i const `pool`?

Comment: now it says `Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No such host is known.
,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.`

Comment: Check your sql server instance name and update to `config` object, ex: `'localhost\\YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME'`. Or enable remote connection for sql server if your app and sql server are not in the same machine.

Comment: my server is online and i'm trying to build API app for it in my PC so diffidently they are in different machines, how do i `enable remote connection for sql server`?

Comment: and my host name is ip based '120.000.000.000\YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME'`

Comment: Create another question, or just get help from your partner who install the sql server. In sort, you need a public ip of sql server.